# Scheduled Azure Webjob with different parameters

Tags: azure, scheduled-tasks

I have a console application which is called at different times with different parameters:

```
myapp.exe daily // starts every day
myapp.exe weekly // starts once a week
```

in Windows I call these using the Task Scheduler

Now I need to deploy this zu Azure. I know I can define a schedule in settings.json like this:

```
{
    "schedule": "0 0 1 * * *"
}
```

Now my two problems are:

- How to add multiple Schedules
- How to add a startup-parameter for each of these schedules

I need to deploy my code automatically via Azure DevOps so manually changing parameters like suggested there does not really work for me:

> To pass parameters to the WebJob you need to go to the scheduled job
>   (in the management portal) and update the url that is used to invoke
>   the triggered WebJob.
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113977/680026

Comment: If you are using webjob, you can use a timertrigger ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36218203/continuous-webjob-with-timer-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the post you've referenced is actually relevant yet bit outdated. Azure Scheduler service is being phased out in favor of Azure Logic Apps, so what you need to do is:

1. Create a new logic app with the "Recurrence" trigger, set the desired (let's say daily) interval in it;
2. Add "HTTP" action using POST method and your WebJob API URL with 'daily' argument;
3. Create another logic app with a weekly interval and 'weekly' argument in HTTP action's URL.

Here is the screenshot of the Logic App I've sketched for a daily trigger:
[image]